# ESP8266 HTTP get request is returning invalid http code -1

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

Normal response would be 200 but i am getting -1, explained below. i have tried using http://www.google.com https://www.google.com and [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) no luck here! apart from this i had tried a lot of different techniques but cant make it, need help!

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h> 

WiFiClient client;
HTTPClient http;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");
  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  delay(500);

      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("WiFi Smart Config Mode Activated");
      WiFi.beginSmartConfig();
      while(!WiFi.smartConfigDone()){
        for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
          delay(200);
          Serial.print("*");
        }
      }
}
void loop()
{
  Serial.print("Http Code: ");
  Serial.println(net_connectivity_check());
}
int net_connectivity_check()
{
    http.begin("https://www.google.com");
    delay(500);
    int internet_chk = http.GET();
    return internet_chk;
}
```

`i have tried with both http:// and https://`

```
WiFi Smart Config Mode Activated
***************************************************************Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
Http Code: -1
```

[Screenshot of Code and Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJPiM.png)

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/200e47fc7ba2fc51952c734a9006bfe47e1ca6bd/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h#L46

Comment: Are you sure SmartConfig is working?  Have you tried setting the SSID and password explicitly as shown here https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap07%20-%20Wi-Fi%20Connections.html

Comment: you wear out the flash memory with disconnecting and connecting at every reset if you didn't set WiFi.persistent(false);. And if you set it, then why to call disconnect() as first?

Comment: Everything is working except this http request, Wifi.Disconnect is just a mistake

Comment: I think your problem is https.  Google redirects http to https and I don't believe they support an unsecured connection anymore.  In any case, you need to supply a fingerprint to http.begin in order to make a connection to https.  See here: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=515541.0

Comment: Take a look at [BasicHttpsClient](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino), you need to establish a secure http connection when accessing Google.com

Answer (score 0):

The connectivity check that you have implemented attempts to access a site over HTTPS.

The HTTPClient library requires you to supply a fingerprint for the certificate that google use. This can be done with the following snippet of code:

```
http.begin("https://www.google.com",
           "3C:88:7E:59:77:A7:55:55:3A:65:A8:E1:7D:65:D5:58:F0:6B:77:49");
```